# How is focus handled with multiple components in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using BrightScript and SceneGraph components to display multiple custom components on one page..? How is focus handled with multiple components in Roku?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple components in one Screen. It's Possible in Roku. But Focus handle in two or more components create a [Panel Set](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/sliding-panels-nodes/panelset.md) and In a panel, Get your component as a child. Here the Best Example [SlidingPanel](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/scenegraph/sliding-panels-nodes/overview.md) Which Provided by Roku Community. Here careful for one thing only panel nodes classes are handle in PanelSet not handle any other Component.

**Example:**

1) In main.brs Set `scene = screen.CreateScene("NikPanel")`

2) create a panel.brs and panel.xml and make sure in XML file component is NikPanel.

3) and in brs file `m.panelset = createObject("roSGNode", "PanelSet")`

4) you create a roSGNode and your component as child. you create a also component wise file.

Comment: Thanks for quickly answer...I'll try

Comment: It's Definitely Woking. I have tried on this. Its Work For me. If any problem pls ask.

Comment: can we use panel-set without Slide and use one screen for multiple custom components..?

Comment: I explain in simple way panel set behave like one Frame Its Display in the main screen and u put anything in a frame.

Comment: can we execute function without onKeyEvent( ) ..?

Comment: No, It's not possible. you should write an onKeyEvent() in PanelSet.